# How to delete the values from html selected list box in on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to Jquery. I couldn't delete the values 3 by 3 & If i click "Remove Category" button, selecting 1, 1, 1. Its not removing and in some cases its deleting 1 by 1 or 2 by 2. I couldn't understand what is happening. All i want is, every three values that i'm going to select should be deleted from bottom as 3 by 3 on every button(Remove Category) click.

```js
var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();
$('#add-category').click(function() {
  $(
    '.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2'
  ).each(function() {
    $('#selected-lst-values').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
  });
});
$('#remove-category').click(function() {
  $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').each(function() {
    var the_index = $(this).val() - 1;
    $('#selected-lst-values')
      .find('option:nth-last-of-type(' + the_index + ')')
      .remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category,
.select-manage-category1,
.select-manage-category2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select></div>

<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<p class="text-center color-red">You can add up to 20 categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category">
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="5">
  </select></div>
<button class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save</strong> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the explanation..Please see the updated js fiddle

```js
var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();
$('#add-category').click(function() {

  $(
    '.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2'
  ).each(function() {
    $('#selected-lst-values').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
  });
});

$('#remove-category').click(function(){
var length=$('#selected-lst-values option').length; //total no of items in the fourth box
//remove the last three on each click
for( var i=0; i<3 ;i++)
{
 $('#selected-lst-values option:eq(' + (length - 1) + ')').remove();
length --;
}
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category,.select-manage-category1,.select-manage-category2{
 width:100px;
 float:left;
 margin-right:4px;
}
p{clear:left;text-align:center;}

#selected-lst-values{
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  </div>
<div>
<p class="text-center color-red">You can add up to 20 categories</p></div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category">
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="5">
  </select></div>
<button class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save</strong> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span>
</button>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3wntyn9/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this js will work for you.
Replace the remove function with this

```js
$('#remove-category').click(function(){
  var index= $('.select-manage-category')[0].selectedIndex || $('.select-manage-category1')[0].selectedIndex || $('.select-manage-category2')[0].selectedIndex;
  $('.select-manage-category option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
  $('.select-manage-category1 option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
  $('.select-manage-category2 option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category,.select-manage-category1,.select-manage-category2{
 width:100px;
 float:left;
 margin-right:4px;
}
p{clear:left;text-align:center;}

#selected-lst-values{
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  </div>
<div>
<p class="text-center color-red">You can add up to 20 categories</p></div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category">
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="5">
  </select></div>
<button class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save</strong> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span>
</button>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3wntyn9/11/)

Comment: @Mary - Thank you. But, I don't want to remove the values in first three boxes. Those are fixed & I want remove the selected values those are in the fourth list box. i.e I selects any three values from first three boxes and I click "Add category" button. So, Those selected values would be in the fourth box. I want these values to be removed 3 by 3 from bottom(From the last three values i selected to the first three values i selectd ).

Comment: so you just want to clear the #selected-list-values each time you click remove button and add the newly clicked ones.Is it?

Comment: I am not 100% clear on your purpose of 'Remove Category' button.can you try this updated fiddle and let me know if thats what you wanted

Comment: In the new fiddle , i have edited both the click functions                                   `- Add category : removes the last entry and add new entry                              - Remove Category: clear the fourth box`

Comment: I think i didn't explain you clearly :) - i.e Firstly, I select any three values from the first three boxes, Then i click "Add Category". So, The selected three values will be in the forth box. Again, I select any three values from the first three boxes and I click "Add Category" button. So, Totally 6 values will be there in fourth box. Now, When i click(first click) "Remove Category" button, The three values should be deleted from bottom and I click "Remove Category" button, Now, again three values should be deleted. Likewise, I want reduce values 3 by 3 on every click.

Comment: Now i get it..please see the answer below..thanks for the expalnation